# Angular Load css partially

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-directives, angular4-router

I want to know is there any wany to load or restrict particular css in index HTML.

- Problem Scenario:

I'm using angular 4 where I separated my components as admin and user components. Both the components using their own CSS. But the Problem is When I include '`admin.css`' and '`user.css`' in the index.html both getting merged and giving me some ugly UI. I want to show include '`user.css`' only if the user points to the user's URL and same for the admin scenario if the user points to admin URL, it should load '`admin.css`' give me a suggestion or solution to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello my recommendation is to use a component that will be load the style for your area , in angular you have to follow a web component concept you will be have all the necessary with your component.

Comment: DO NOT reference component styles in your index.html. Use @Component's metadata: `styles` or `styleUrls` properties.

Answer (score 1):

First of all - using Angular 4 - the best practice to include `.css` files for each component.

I mean:

You have a component `user.ts`, so you should to include style for the user to that component, **not to index.html**

**Example:**

user.ts code:

```
@Component
....
styles: ['h1 { font-weight: normal; }']
```

Or

```
@Component
....
styleUrls: ['./user.css']
```

That's will isolate your styles. As it said at Angular docs:

> By default in Angular, when you attach CSS directly to a component, we scope that css exclusively to that component. This scoping isolates it from the rest of your application. This additional capability means that there are two ways to use CSS with Angular.

Answer (score 0):

It 's better and easy if you use sass and create a class flag for user and admin **components** 
like this

theme/_user.scss

```
.user { 
  label { 
    color:red;
  }
}
```

theme/_admin.scss

```
.admin { 
  label {
    color:green;
  }
}
```

and this in main style.scc

```
@import "theme/_user.scss";
@import "theme/_admin.scss";
```

note : _user.scss will have all the style from user.css 
this is much better for app performance you will have one style file with user and admin style

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ko88ec)